# Реализации индикатора загрузки

Tags: ajax, javascript

Существует достаточное количество js-библиотек для реализации индикатора загрузки(выгрузки) данных. Хочу попытаться сделать такое же сам. Но не пойму на чем основан  принцип работы индикатора. Откуда берутся данные о количестве передаваемой информации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE.** Если не использовать способ, предоставляемый *HTML5*, то можно пытаться создать скрытый `<iframe>`, через который производить загрузку файла. Так, насколько я знаю, делает *Google*, а так же куча Javascript-библиотек. Для *jQuery*, например, есть [такое решение](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload). Но это изрядно бубен.

Остальные способы включают использование других клиентских технологий, вроде *Flash*. Например, [SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/).

---

Если вы хотите узнать о *стандартном* способе, не привлекающем *Flash* или тому подобное, то новый `XMLHttpRequest` в *HTML5* выставляет в том числе и событие `onprogress`, вызываемое, когда изменяется статус текущей загрузки данных на сервер. С помощью этого события можно отслеживать количество переданных данных.

[Вот тут](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) есть подробное описание, как это можно сделать. Вот пример.

```
function upload(blobOrFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

  // Наблюдаем за процессом закачки.
  var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
      progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Если бразуер не поддерживает.
    }
  };

  // Отправляем данные на сервер.
  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}

upload(new Blob(['hello world'], {type: 'text/plain'}));
```

Comment: А, ну да, это все встроено в html5, спасибо за ответ. А как насчет "ссамодельного" индикатора? Без привлечения встроенных сущностей. Реально ли? Используя только js и ajax?

Comment: @Deus Обновил ответ. Если помогло, лучше + нажать =)